# Oscillatory and exponential behaviour of second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I have come across this phrase used often while explaining the behaviour of the  [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) (which is the solution of $y''-xy=0$): *the behaviour of the solution changes from oscillatory to exponential at the point 0*. In this very special example of the Airy function, I can intuitively understand why the behaviour for $x<0$ is called oscillatory and the behaviour for $x>0$ is called exponential.

Here are my questions:

1. Consider the following Sturm-Liouville equation on the interval $[a,b]$,
   $$
   \frac{d}{dx}[p(x)f'(x)] + q(x)f(x) = 0.
   $$
   Is there a rigorous classification/definiton for the  behaviour of the solution of the above equation as oscillatory or exponential? If we assume $p>0$ on $[a,b]$, then my guess is that if at all there is a definition, it must classify the solution as oscillatory on the interval where $q>0$ and as exponential when $q<0$.
2. Secondly, I am aware of the Polya-Sonin theorem which is used to study the oscillatory behaviour of a solution (this is used to obtain the Bernstein inequality for Legendre polynomials and also to study the oscillatory behaviour of Bessel functions, Jacobi polynomials etc, just to name a few). Are there any such general methods/theorems to analyse the solution when it is exponential?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to construct a situation where you can apply the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, from that you definitively get oscillating behavior if the interval under consideration is large enough.